# $_SESSION not storing values

Tags: php, session

I am having an issue with storing $_SESSION variables, i am a little new at PHP and I like it to the extent of my current knowledge.

first my creds:

Win 7 Pro 64
PHP 5
Remote Server(not sure of its config)

So what I am trying to do is set up a Login Page that contains a hardcoded username and password for testing purposes.

I want to display the username on a successor page to confirm it.

Login.php

```
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head >
<title>Login</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-gb" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Perform Client side validation of Username and Password
    function redirect() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username");
        var password = (document.getElementById("password"));

        if (!username.value == " ") {
             if (!password.value == " ") {
                if (username.value == "aknight") {
                    if (password.value == "00226291") {
                        window.location = "Home.php";
                        exit();
                    } else
                        alert("Username or Password Invalid");
                }
            } else
                alert("Password is required");
        } else
            alert("Username is required");
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Product Order System</h1>
<br/>
<h2>The most expensive crap youll ever find...</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

}else{
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login Information</legend>
<p>
<label for="Username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="Password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" name="login" value="Login" onclick="redirect();"/>
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php }

    include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$page_title = 'Home';
include ('includes/header.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { $name = $_SESSION['username'];}else{echo "<p>error</p>";}
echo "<h3>Welcome ".$name."!</h3>" ;
?>
```

I have tried printing out the `$_SESSION` values and they are coming up empty.

producing this result

```
<?php
   echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION)."</pre>";
?>

Array {
    [username] => 
}
```

Please do not mind the JS, it is preschool client validation just to move forward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give your login form a name, and then in your JavaScript validation function, instead of window.location, do a document.forms['yourformname'].submit().

Comment: I try to avoid using Form in JS, but it makes sense here, was a big over sight.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Javascript validation is actually what's causing the issue.
You're setting the session variable in Login.php using the POST request, but no POST is actually being sent to Login.php since your Javascript is redirecting to Home.php once the form is considered valid. You need to submit the form at some point in the process, so you actually get some POST values which you'll use to populate your SESSION variables.
If you want to keep your Javascript validation, maybe have a look at submit() : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp
You'll have to set a correct action property on your form before submitting it.

Comment: I didnt really see that I wasnt posting anything to login.php, and using the submit() for JS allows the post to happen, invoking the header() works great as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So heres a fix that seems to be working

```
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head >
<title>Login</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-gb" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Perform Client side validation of Username and Password
    function redirect() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username");
        var password = (document.getElementById("password"));

        if (!username.value == " ") {
            if (!password.value == " ") {
                if (username.value == "aknight") {
                    if (password.value == "00226291") {
                        document.forms[0].submit();
                        exit();
                    } else
                        alert("Username or Password Invalid");

                }
            } else
                alert("Password is required");

        } else
            alert("Username is required");

    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Product Order System</h1>
<br/>
<h2>The most expensive crap youll ever find...</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header('Location : ../Home.php');

}else{
?>

<form action="Home.php" name="login" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login Information</legend>
<p>
<label for="Username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="Password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" name="login" value="Login" onclick=" redirect();"/>
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php }

    include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Will post again if the nex series of pages has a similiar issue

Thanks